# how to use split or other function for extracting information from text file having xml tags

Tags: java, filereader

Hi I do have flat text files having data in form like this

```
<PersonName> Ian </PersonName> <OrgName> Cum Sociis Natoque Limited</OrgName>
<PersonName> Camilla </PersonName> <OrgName> Lorem Corporation </OrgName>
<PersonName> Addison </PersonName> <OrgName> Tempus Corp. </OrgName>
<PersonName> Arsenio </PersonName> <OrgName> Id LLP </OrgName>
```

I want the final outcome like this:

```
Ian: PersonName
Cum Sociis Natoque Limited: OrgName
Camilla: PersonName
.... so on
```

does anyone have any insights

Comment: if you using java, then JAXB might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your file is **really a plain text file** not an `XML` file, you could use a **regular expression** to extract the text content between the `XML` tags, as next:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([^>]+)>([^<]*)</[^>]+>");
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s ", matcher.group(2).trim(), matcher.group(1));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<PersonName> Ian </PersonName> <OrgName> Cum Sociis Natoque Limited</OrgName>
Ian: PersonName Cum Sociis Natoque Limited: OrgName 
<PersonName> Camilla </PersonName> <OrgName> Lorem Corporation </OrgName>
Camilla: PersonName Lorem Corporation: OrgName 
<PersonName> Addison </PersonName> <OrgName> Tempus Corp. </OrgName>
Addison: PersonName Tempus Corp.: OrgName 
<PersonName> Arsenio </PersonName> <OrgName> Id LLP </OrgName>
Arsenio: PersonName Id LLP: OrgName
```

---

In **java 8**, it would be:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([^>]+)>([^<]*)</[^>]+>");
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
    stream.forEach(
        line -> {
            System.out.println(line);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.printf("%s: %s ", matcher.group(2).trim(), matcher.group(1));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Yeah file is a text file but having some xml tag data.Tags pattern is not predefined i mean to say tags counts are changed across the text file like this.Paid to Tech Support <PersonName> Nathaniel </PersonName> <PersonName> Zia </PersonName>
Paid to Media Relations <PersonName> Ray </PersonName> <PersonName> Fleur </PersonName>

Comment: Thanks Nicolas It's Working.I need to do one slightly change in the outcome.I need to print original text as well after extracting the tags data like this... <PersonName> Ian </PersonName> <OrgName> Cum Sociis Natoque Limited</OrgName>                                                                                       Ian: PersonName
Cum Sociis Natoque Limited: OrgName

Comment: No..In first line original text and in next line extracted xml tag data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Use split on each line:

```
String[] parts = line.replaceAll("^.*?>", "").split("<.*?>");
```

Which will be an array of size 2 with the stuff you want.